# How to sort the array by the value of given key in my case?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to sort the array by the value of the given key `0` in this case.

So here is my array:

```
array(11) { 
[0]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "5" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3" 
 [2]=> string(2) "21" 
} 
[1]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "0.5" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3" 
 [2]=> string(3) "may" 
} 
[2]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "2.2" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3"
 [2]=> string(16) "sport" 
}  
}
```

Result must be sorted by the value of key `0`:

```
    array(11) { 
[0]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "0.5" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3" 
 [2]=> string(2) "may" 
} 
[1]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "2.2" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3" 
 [2]=> string(3) "sport" 
} 
[2]=> array(3) { 
 [0]=> string(3) "5" 
 [1]=> string(1) "3"
 [2]=> string(16) "21" 
}  
}
```

I attempted it with this code:

```
function sort_by_second($i,$j){return $i[0]-$j[0];};
usort($mas,'sort_by_second');
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you getting right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below code:**

```
$array = array(
             array("5","3","21"),
             array("0.5","3","may"),
             array("2.2","3","sport"),
          );

//print_r($array);

function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}

$result = subval_sort($array, 0);

print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.5
            [1] => 3
            [2] => may
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.2
            [1] => 3
            [2] => sport
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 21
        )

)
```

**Demo:**

http://3v4l.org/q4ZtL#v430

Answer (score 0):

PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 0), SORT_ASC, $array);
```